# Split array into smaller arrays separated by ''

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to split an array into smaller arrays separated by  ""?

I have an array which looks like this:

```
`[
  '1000', '2000',  '3000',
  '',     '4000',  '',
  '5000', '6000',  '',
  '7000', '8000',  '9000',
  '',     '10000'
]
`
```

I need arrays which would look like this:

```
`  ['1000', '2000',  '3000',]
  [ '4000'] 
  ['5000', '6000' ]
  ['7000', '8000',  '9000']
  [ '10000']
`
```

Any help is useful

Comment: @flyingfox see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593 and also idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I tried googling for 2 hours, did not help

Comment: If the exact solution you're looking for can't be found easily already, then the first step would be to try writing some code to accomplish the goal you're aiming for

Answer (score 0):

We can first find all the index for value is empty,then using `Array.slice()` to do it.

Below is a simple reference for you(not fully tested yet，such as multiple empty elements **appear continuously**)

```js
let arr = [
  '1000', '2000',  '3000',
  '',     '4000',  '',
  '5000', '6000',  '',
  '7000', '8000',  '9000',
  '',     '10000'
]

const convertArray = data => {
  let pos = []
  data.forEach((v,i) =>{
     if(!v){
       pos.push(i)
     }
  })

  let result = []
  let prev = 0
  for(p of pos){
    result.push(data.slice(prev,p))
    prev = p + 1
  }
  result.push(data.slice(prev))
  return result
}


console.log(convertArray(arr))
```

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me , hope this works for your too..

```
   const arr = [
    '1000', '2000', '3000',
    '', '4000', '',
    '5000', '6000', '',
    '7000', '8000', '9000',
    '', '10000'
]

const newArr = []
let index = 0

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == '') {
        const newArrSet = []
        for(let j = i ; j > index ; j-- ){
            console.log('revese' , arr[j] ,  i)
            newArrSet.push(arr[j])
        }
        newArr.push(newArrSet)
        index = i
    }

}
   const mappedArray = newArr.map((item)=>{
     return item.filter(item=> item !== '')
   })

   console.log(mappedArray)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make your answer more useful by explaining why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question